# C# - Ordering dictionary with multiple ordering criteria

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dictionary

I have a dictionary of word frequencies and need to order them first by frequency, then alphabetically (if multiple words have the same word count they will be ordered alphabetically, not 2 separate orderings)
The dictionary has the word as the key and the frequency as the value.

How would I be able to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dictionary is by its nature an unordered structure. Maybe it is better to pick another structure if you want ordering

Comment: Please show sample dictionary. Why order a dictionary? What have you tried?

Comment: A Dictionary isn't an ordered collection. You might want to go with a [`sortedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: .orderby().ThenBy()?

Answer (score 2):

While the dictionary is not an ordered collection, if you have a dictionary and what to get an ordered collection from that, you can use LINQ to easily do the ordering:

```
var ordered = values.OrderByDescending(_ => _.Value).ThenBy(_ => _.Key);
```

**Note** Each time you iterate the `ordered` `IEnumerable` the sorting will reoccur, so depending on usage you may want to add a `ToList()` to have a concrete collection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the most frequent words first, then:

```
foreach(var pair in theData.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ThenBy(x => x.Key)) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}: {pair.Value}");
}
```